# Unable to use QML QtGamepad under Linux

Tags: qt, qml

I am unable to use QGamepad in QML under Linux.

By "unable" I mean no gamepad signal is emitted (button pressed...)

Configuration:

- Ubuntu 20.04
- Qt 5.15
- Logitech Gamepad F310

Gamepad is well recognized by Ubuntu:

- dmesg gives:

> usb 1-1.6: Product: Gamepad F310 
> input: Logitech Gamepad F310 as /devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:1a.0/usb1/1-1/1-1.6/1-1.6:1.0/input/input26

- jstest-gtk recognizes gamepad well:

> Logitech Gamepad F310
> Device: /dev/input/js0
> and is responsive when pressing buttons

Sample QML code:

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtGamepad 1.15

Rectangle {
    width: 320
    height: 240
    Gamepad {
        onButtonAChanged: {
            console.log("ButtonA")
        }
        onButtonBChanged: {
            console.log("ButtonB")
        }
    }
}
```

I tried to define QT_GAMEPAD and QT_GAMEPAD_DEVICE env variables, but without any improvment.

```
export QT_GAMEPAD=evdev
export QT_GAMEPAD_DEVICE=/dev/input/js0
```

Note: the same QML code is working well under MS Windows 10 (same Qt version).

Comment: Linux has 2 game controller subsystems: older `joystick`(`/dev/input/js*`) and newer `evdev` (`/dev/input/by-id/usb-*-event-joystick` aka `/dev/input/event*`). Qt supports only `evdev`. `js*` can be used in Qt via `SDL` but Qt must be built from source with `SDL` enabled. XOrg has its own API which is not used by Qt. To load drivers: `sudo modprobe usbhid` `sudo modprobe joydev`. Use `evdev-joystick` to configure and `evtest` to test evdev - see their `man`s. If `evtest` not working ask on `ubuntu`/`unix` forums first. Otherwise supply correct `QT_GAMEPAD_DEVICE` and report results

Comment: Thank you Jack. I did:
sudo modprobe usbhid --> OK
sudo modprobe joydev --> OK
evtest --> OK (gamepad detected on event8 and gamepad buttons are detected)
export QT_GAMEPAD=evdev
export  QT_GAMEPAD_DEVICE=/dev/input/event8
But still no signal on button pressed in QML app.
There is no error message when executing QML app.

Comment: @kleio12345 try execute: `QT_DEBUG_PLUGINS="1" ./your_executable` in terminal

Comment: Could there be a conflict between the drivers? (Xorg driver intercepting events before QtML app)

Comment: @eyllanesc everything seems ok: Found metadata in lib libdeclarative_gamepad.so, Found metadata in lib libevdevgamepad.so, Got keys from plugin meta data ("evdev")

Comment: If you have `xboxdrv` running or `xpad`/`hidraw` drivers, you can try unloading them by `killall xboxdrv`, `sudo rmmod xpad`, `sudo rmmod hidraw` - although I don't think it matters if `evtest` works. Insert `GamepadManager` QML element and check contents of its `connectedGamepads` property (note: it may be populated a moment after `Component.onCompleted` fires). Does your actual application write any errors to `stdout/err` (terminal or `Application output` bottom pane in Qt Creator)? Do Qt examples work? try at least `simple` and `qt quick` ones: https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtgamepad-examples.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Jack White this is the solution:

Property deviceId of Gamepad module shall be initialized, using GamepadManager.

```
import QtQuick 2.15
import QtGamepad 1.15
    
Rectangle {
    width: 320
    height: 240
        
    Gamepad {
        deviceId: GamepadManager.connectedGamepads.length > 0 ? GamepadManager.connectedGamepads[0] : -1
                
        onButtonAChanged: {
           console.log("ButtonA");
        }
        onButtonBChanged: {
           console.log("ButtonB");
        }
     }
}
```